# Adding object.id to render to string to avoid django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, django-urls

I have a Django project that starts with a List view and when one of the objects are clicked it goes to a detailed view which has a button. When this button is clicked I am using Ajax to change a boolean from False to True value. So far I have reached to the point where when the button is clicked it changes the boolean in the backend using Ajax but the page still needs to be manually refreshed to show the effect of the boolean change. I am getting a `No Reverse Match Error` which can seem to solve it.

In my project I have a Detail view as following

```
class workout_details(DetailView):
    model = Workout
    template_name = 'my_gym/start_workout.html'
    context_object_name = 'workout'

def change_status(request, id):
    context = {}

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        startsession = Workout.objects.get(id=id)
        if request.POST.get('active') == 'true':
            startsession.active = True
            startsession.save()
            context.update({'status': 'success'})
            context.update({'active': str(startsession.active)})
        html = render_to_string('my_gym/start_workout.html', context)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Here is the template `my_gym/start_workout.html` :

```
        <!-- button -->
            <div id="startworkout">
            {% include 'my_gym/button.html' %}
            </div>
        <!-- button -->
```

Here is the `my_gym/button.html`:

```
            <form action="{% url 'my_gym:bla' object.id %}" method='post'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if object.active %}
                    <button disabled  type="button">Start the workout</button>
                    {% else %}
                      <button value="true" id="customSwitches" onclick="start();" type="button">Start the workout</button>
                    {% endif  %}
            </form>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(event){
                    $(document).on('click','#customSwitches', function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var status= $(this).attr('value');
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url:'{% url 'my_gym:bla' object.id %}',
                            data:{'active' : status, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'{{csrf_token}}'},
                            dataType:'json',
                            success:function(response){
                                $('#startworkout').html(response['form'])
                                console.log($('#startworkout').html(response['form']));
                            },
                            error:function(rs, e){
                                console.log(rs.responseText);
                            },
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

here is the views.py:

```
app_name = 'my_gym'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('workout/<int:pk>/', workout_details.as_view(), name='workout'),
    path('workout/bla/<int:id>/', change_status, name='bla'),
]
```

----------------UPDATE----------------

@SOM-1 gave comments which made me update the views to the following as it is missing context and now I getting an error in the terminal as `Not Found: /workout/bla/1/`

Here is the updated Views:

```
def change_status(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        workout = get_object_or_404(Workout, id=request.POST.get('id'))
        if request.POST.get('active') == 'true':
            workout.active = True
            workout.save()
            context = {
                'status': 'success',
                'workout': workout,
            }
            html = render_to_string('my_gym/button.html', context)
            print("Sucess")
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
        else:
            print("FAIL")
    else:
        print("FAIL")
```

None of the fail prints are being printed only `NOT FOUND`

Comment: Where do you put an object in your context? This error means argument for reversing is empty, and it's empty, because it's not in context. Also, regarding ajax - if you manually refresh the page, why do you need ajax anymore? The purpose of ajax is to NOT refresh the page - so when you are using ajax, after receiving a response you should redraw required elements on the page with javascript.

Comment: @Som-1 could you elaborate more as I am not sure what do u mean. For the ajax because of the error I am refreshing the page manually ... the purpose of adding the ajax in my project is preventing refreshing

Comment: I mean, here `render_to_string('my_gym/start_workout.html', context)` you are rendering a template to string and passing context dictionary, which has `status` and `active` keys. But in the template you are reversing url  `{% url 'my_gym:bla' object.id %}` with `object.id` as an argument. So there must be an `object` key in context passed to a template, which should be an object having id, `startsession` I assume. It is not set anywhere by view, so Django's template engine renders it as empty string: `Reverse for 'bla' with arguments '('',)'` - arguments is a tuple of empty string.

Comment: And for AJAX, here you say `... the page still needs to be manually refreshed ...`, so I think it was something wrong with AJAX using. Either you do not need AJAX, just plain post the form and refresh the page, or you do not need to render the template, but should update elements on the page with JS instead after a successfull request. Or I did not understand, what did you mean. Also I've seen such a technique of rendering templates for small parts of the page for AJAX responses. And it's quite interesting, it might be easier then writing javascript, and still not too heavy for the server.

Comment: @Som-1 I have updated the question I have added the context but now as shown i am getting an error in the terminal as not found.

Comment: Don't get id here as `request.POST.get('id')`, it's for data posted via form. But in your case id is a part of url, and Django parses it and passes as a an argument to you view: `def change_status(request, id)`: - here it is. Next, here you are putting a workout object into context under `workout` key: `context = {..., 'workout': workout,}`, but template still expects `object` key, so try renaming `workout` to `object` in the context like this: `context = {..., 'object': workout,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`{% url 'my_gym:bla' id=object.id %}`** instead of `{% url 'my_gym:bla' object.id %}`

Comment: now it is returning `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'bla' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['workout/bla/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
`

Comment: Are you sure the `object.id` is a non-empty value?

Comment: yes in order to make sure that it is not an empty I keep printing {{ object.id }} in the template to make sure it is not null it is currently showing `1`

Comment: is there another way to debug it to make sure it is not empty?